# Print table from array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with following format:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Push to Web] => Yes
            [attribute_set] => laminate_flooring
            [category] => Accessories/Underlay
            [name] => Under Pad Feather Light Foam
            [sku] => 123-1028
            [description] => Floor Underlayment Feather Light (Vapour Barrier) 200 Sqft/Roll
            [short_description] => Floor Underlayment Feather Light (Vapour Barrier) 200 Sqft/Roll
            [image] => 123-1028.jpg
            [gallery_Image] => 9095307460638-424-424.jpg
            [price] => 0.24
            [qty_ca] => 16
            [weight] => 3
            [meta_description] => 51-1001
            [meta_title] => Under Pad Feather Light Foam
            [status] => 1
            [flooring_coverage] => 200
            [is_flooring_product] => 1
            [web_price_comparative] => 0.31
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Push to Web] => Yes
            [category] => Accessories
            [name] => Vent Maple Flush 4x10
            [sku] => 089-1000
            [description] => Vent Flush Mount Maple 4 x 10
            [short_description] => Vent Flush Mount Maple 4 x 10
            [image] => 089-1000.jpg
            [price] => 17.05
            [qty_ca] => 63
            [qty_us] => 41
            [meta_description] => 10-1023
            [meta_title] => Vent Maple Flush 4x10
            [status] => 1
            [flooring_coverage] => 1
            [min_order_qty] => 400
            [web_price_comparative] => 22.16
        )
)
```

I have to print the data in the table so that each key of array is printed as column header and the value as column data. That means Push to Web, attribute_set etc will be header and Yes, laminate_flooring will be data respectively.

I wrote the following but its not working.

```
$table  = '<table border="1" id="datatable">
<tr>';
foreach($data as $key=>$value){
    $table .= '<td>'.$key.'</td>';
}
$table .= '</tr>';
foreach($data as $value){
    $table .=   '<tr>';
    foreach($value as $innerkey=>$innervalue){
                $table .=   '<td>'.$innervalue.'</td>';
             }
             $table .= '</tr>';
        }
    }
 }
 $table .= '</table>';

 print_r($table);
```

Please help me to sort out the problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: *I wrote the following but its not working* - can you show an example of the result which shows where the problem is.

Comment: May be `array_keys()` and `array_values()` will help. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys & https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php  Also use the alternate notation of `foreach()` when using inside HTML. It will look much cleaner. `<?php foreach($array as $element): #your code endforeach; ?> `

Comment: I am getting 0, 1,2,3 ........ the keys as the header rows.

Comment: Also arrays don't have keys or values are filled by next value. so no blank cell is here. But there should be some blank cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you get 0,1,2 in the header keys.. etc....

```
foreach($data as $key=>$value){
    $table .= '<td>'.$key.'</td>';
}
```

This is because your top level keys are:

```
0
1
2
3..
```

In the next level you have these keys:

```
Push to Web
Category
Name
etc..
```

In this code snippet you add the `innervalue`-data (*push to web-value, category-value, name-value* etc...)...

```
foreach($data as $value){
    $table .=   '<tr>';
    foreach($value as $innerkey=>$innervalue){
        $table .= '<td>'.$innervalue.'</td>';
    }
    $table .= '</tr>';
}
```

...these values are on the same level as the key you want. Therefore `$innerkey` is the key you want to add in the **header**:

```
foreach($data as $value){
    $table .= '<tr>';
    foreach($value as $innerkey=>$innervalue){
        $table .= '<td>'.$innerkey.'</td>';
    }
    $table .= '</tr>';
}
```

So the logic is basically something like this:

```
$table  = '<table border="1" id="datatable">';
foreach($data as $key=>$value){
    $table .= '<tr>';
    foreach($value as $innerkey=>$innervalue){
        $table .= '<td>'.$innerkey.'</td>';
    }
    $table .= '</tr>';
}
foreach($data as $value){
    $table .= '<tr>';
    foreach($value as $innerkey=>$innervalue){
        $table .= '<td>'.$innervalue.'</td>';
    }
    $table .= '</tr>';
}
$table .= '</table>';
```

Based on above logic - you can do like this to achieve what you want:

**UPDATE**

Now that I understand that all keys does not exists in all items. You could do like this:

```
//Because you have different keys in different item
//you could recreate each item in the array
//Based on the the $use_keys array here 
//(add all keys you want to use and $use_keys set the order of the keys in 
//each item!)
$use_keys = ['pushweb', 'attribute set', 'category', 'name'];

//Go through the whole array and recreate it with keys given
//in $use_keys
foreach($data as $key=>$value){ 

    //Create a new array with key values from array $use_keys
    $new_arr = [];
    foreach($use_keys as $apk_item) {
        //Add key/value to the new array. If value already exist
        //in the $data[key] then use that value, else just empty string
        $new_value = '';
        if (isset($data[$key][$apk_item])) {
            $new_value = $data[$key][$apk_item];
        }            
        $new_arr[$apk_item] = $new_value;                
    }
    //Recreate the data[key] part of the original data array
    $data[$key] = $new_arr;
}

//Then same code as before
$row = 0;
$table  = '<table border="1" id="datatable">';
foreach($data as $value){
    $table .= '<tr>';
    if ($row == 0) {
        foreach($value as $innerkey=>$innervalue){
            $table .= '<td>'.$innerkey.'</td>';
        }    
    }
    $table .= '</tr><tr>';
    foreach($value as $innerkey=>$innervalue){
        $table .= '<td>'.$innervalue.'</td>';
    }
    $table .= '</tr>';
    $row++;
}
$table .= '</table>';
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. header row is showing but not all columns. only columns having available in the first array. Secondly  arrays don't have keys or values are filled by next value. so no blank cell is here. But there should be some blank cells.

Comment: I dont understand. Can you please update your question and tell what output you want from your example array?

Comment: I actually need the table like this https://ibb.co/zn9zNgR. But getting lik this https://ibb.co/LSy2sYb and this https://ibb.co/Tbg92jb

Comment: It seems weird you have a different set of keys for each item in the array? (Attribute-set is set in the first item but not in the second in your example).

Comment: yes. If the key doesn't exists the cell would be blank or null.

Comment: Ok now I understand the actual issue. I'll be back with a solution...

Comment: Awesome. Love from me fro your lifesaver code. Thanks :)

Comment: haha lifesave code might some exaggeration but you're welcome!